# Array assignment with struct pointers in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I need to hold a dynamic array of structs.

The types are defined like this. I'm not able to change those, because they are given by a library called flint (library for fast number theory).

```
typedef struct
{
    mp_ptr coeffs;
    slong alloc;
    slong length;
    nmod_t mod;
} nmod_poly_struct;

typedef nmod_poly_struct nmod_poly_t[1];
```

and my struct is defined like this:

```
typedef struct {
    mp_limb_t D;
    mp_limb_t length;
    nmod_poly_t *s;
} she_key_symmetric_t;
```

So my problem is to hold a set of nmod_poly_t objects. I initialize them and want so store them in the array.

```
nmod_poly_t poly;
nmod_poly_init(poly);

she_key_symmetric_t key;
// init and stuff
key.s[0] = poly; // This line does not work, because 
// it always says "array type 'nmod_poly_t' (aka 
// 'nmod_poly_struct[1]') is not assignable"
```

In the next step I have to get the values back out of the array

```
she_key_symmetric_t key;
// fully initialized key
nmod_poly_t poly = key.s[0];
```

So how do I need to declare my dynamic array **s** to store my strucs inside it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you wanting a solution in C or C++?  The answers may be very different depending on which you choose.

Comment: *nmod_poly_t poly = key.s[0];* => *nmod_poly_t poly; poly[0] =key.s[0][0]; actually works.* Plain C is preferred.

Comment: Removing C++ tag, since it seems like C++ isn't really the language being asked about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following will work, assuming memory allocated properly for `key.s` and initialized

```
nmod_poly_t poly; 
poly[0] =key.s[0][0];
```